# why isn't it printing the right number of a's?

Tags: python

```
list =["jojo","gardan","giga"]

number_of_a = 0

for item in list:

    if "a" in item:

        number_of_a += 1
        print("there is "+str(number_of_a)+ " a's in "+ item)
    else :
        print("sorry")
```

Comment: You have basically asked the computer "how many of these items have a in them?"  Is that what you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 1):

so from my understanding you want to count the occurrences of a letter in a string

to do that in python the simplest way would be to use the count method, like this:

```
for word in list:
  number_of_a += word.count("a")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking whether `a` exists in each of the strings, not how many of them there are. `if "a" in item:` will return `True` if there's letter "a" in the string and False otherwise. And then you add 1 to the counter.

So here the first string will return False and the variable will remain 0, but then the second string will change it to 1 and the last string will make it 2. If you want to calculate number of "a" in each of the strings, you need to make sure to re-set the value of the counter for each of the strings and then you need to actually count the number of "a" by for example iterating over all characters or using `count` as others have suggested:

```
list_ =["jojo","gardan","giga"]

for item in list_:
    number_of_a = 0
    for i in item:
        if i == 'a':
            number_of_a += 1
        else:
            continue
        
    if number_of_a:
        print("there is "+str(number_of_a)+ " a's in "+ item)
    else :
        print("sorry")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to know how many "a's" are there in each element in the list. Here is the code.

```
l = ["jojo", "gardan", "giga"]
number_of_a = 0

for item in l:
    if "a" in item:
        number_of_a += 1
        print("there is " + str(number_of_a) + " a's in " + item)
    else:
        print("sorry")
```

Output :
sorry
there is 1 a's in gardan
there is 2 a's in giga

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to iterate all character and match with 'a'

```
list =["jojo","gardan","giga"]

number_of_a = 0

for item in list:
    number_of_a = 0
    for i in range(0, len(item)):
        if item[i] == "a":
            number_of_a += 1
      

    print("there is "+str(number_of_a)+ " a's in "+ item)
```

output:

```
there is 0 a's in jojo
there is 2 a's in gardan
there is 1 a's in giga
```

Answer (score -1):

So I’m guessing that item is the part of the list. So your just checking if that item value has a in it. You can fix this buy looping through item

```
for i in range(0, len(item)):
    if item[i] == “a”:
        number_of_a += 1
```